# negative value of position occurs on selected item from AutoComplete TextView

Tags: android, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I am unable to get the correct position of Item from `AutoCompleteTextView`. I got position in minus.Basically i want to select item and get its position but as its a large amount of data I have used `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of just Spinner. So plz suggest better idea if any or correct me .

in my `onCreate` method i have return following code :

```
 actvSource = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.ac_source);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterS = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.bus_stop_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterS.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actvSource.setAdapter(adapterS);

        actvSource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                actvSource.showDropDown();
                sourcePosition = actvSource.getListSelection();
            }
        });
```

and on `Button` click i want its position :

```
btnfare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calci_fare);
btnfare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Source Position", "" + sourcePosition);
        Log.e("Destination Position", "" + destPosition);
}
```

Comment: use `setOnItemClickListener` on the instance of `AutoCompleteTextView`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this

```
actvSource.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
            String selection = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

        });
```

Comment: I have already used that only .please check in my above code

Comment: @CreativeHive I have update my code see below.

Comment: can you explain me what is parent here.as i am new not getting idea.

 String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: @CreativeHive and read this docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html